# Get input from console for enum type

Tags: java, enums

How do you get input from console for `enum` types in java?

I have this class:

```
class enumTest {

  public enum Color {
    RED, BLACK, BLUE
  }

  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  Color color = input.readLine();

  public static void main (String[]args) {

  switch (color) {
    ...
```

On this line `Color color = input.readLine();` i am getting an error which says:

```
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Color
```

How do i get arround this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? They already have values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every enum has an [automatically generated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3) static `valueOf` method which parses a string. So you can use:

```
String colorName = input.readLine();
Color color = Color.valueOf(colorName);
```

However, this will throw an exception if the given name doesn't have any corresponding enum value. You may want to instead create a `Map<String, Color>` (either within `Color` or separately) so that you can handle this more elegantly.

Comment: What do you mean by using a Map?

Comment: @BiancaBalan: Um, I'm not sure how to explain that more clearly. A map with a key that's a string and a value that's the corresponding colour. Do you know about the `Map` interface in general?

Comment: I know, I understand this but I don't know how to use it to handle de exception

Comment: @BiancaBalan: There's no exception in this question... if you've tried implementing this but run into problems, I suggest you ask a new question with all the relevant details.

Comment: Based on your answer ".... this will throw an exception..., You may want to instead create a Map<String, Color>",  I understand that you say that this problem will be fixed if I use a map and I said I don't understand how

Comment: @BiancaBalan: You'd create a map of all the names to colors, then you can call `Color color = map.get(colorName);`. It will return null rather than throwing an exception if there's no matching entry in the map.

Answer (score 1):

Store read line in String variable and then use valueOf method of the Enum class in order to convert string into enum instance.

```
color = Color.valueOf( input.readLine() );
```